# How can I turn off table and figure captions?

Tags: captions

I am using my figures and tables both in report documents, where I want them to have caption text, an in presentations made with Beamer, where I want them to not have a caption text. I am using the Caption package (2011/08/11) both for my report and presentations.

Is there a simple way to turn off the caption text when I use the figures and tables in my presentations?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It is considered a lot better to put in some code that will compile, as it makes it a lot easier for us to copy it into our text editor and work with it, and see exactly what it is you are trying to do.

Comment: How about `\DeclareCaptionFormat{empty}{}\captionsetup{format=empty}`?

Comment: Thanks:) but when I put that string in the preamble I get this:    ! Undefined control sequence.
l.21 \DeclareCaptionFormat
                          {empty}{}\captionsetup{format=empty}

Comment: They are provided by the `caption` package (which you said you're using) so you need to put it after `\usepackage{caption}`

Comment: It works fine !! (I forgot to put the \DeclareCaptionFormat string AFTER the \usepackage{caption} command .

Answer (score 13):

Since you're using the `caption` package already you can use its possibilites to define own caption formats to define one that outputs nothing by saying

```
\DeclareCaptionFormat{empty}{}
```

You can now use this format by setting it with `\captionsetup`:

```
\captionsetup{format=empty}
```

A complete example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{caption}
\DeclareCaptionFormat{empty}{}
\captionsetup{format=empty}
\begin{document} 

\begin{frame}
\begin{figure}
 some figure
 \caption{some caption}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

As noted by Axel Sommerfeldt in the comments it is probably a good idea also to set the skip above and below the caption to zero. Otherwise you might wonder where the vertical space below the figure comes from... For this just extend the caption setup:

```
\captionsetup{format=empty,aboveskip=0pt,belowskip=0pt}
```

Comment: I would set the skips above and below the caption to 0pt additionally, i.e. `\captionsetup{format=empty,aboveskip=0pt,belowskip=0pt}`

Comment: @Axel Good point!

Comment: If the *same* document is producing the article and beamer versions you might want to put the caption formatting commands inside `\mode<presentation>{...}`.

Comment: @Andrew true, but I thought that wouldn't be too hard to figure out if one already is using one document for both :)

Answer (score 4):

(For reference, without any package.) Put this into your preamble:

```
\makeatletter
\def\@gobblebracket[#1]{}
\def\caption{\@ifnextchar[{\expandafter\@gobble\@gobblebracket}\@gobble}
\makeatother
```

or even simpler (credit to Andrew):

```
\renewcommand \caption [2][]{}
```

Comment: `\renewcommand{\caption}[2][]{}`

Comment: @AndrewStacey Damn those LaTeXy smarties!